# Calculations by group in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that I would like to run some calculations on. It looks like this:

```
User  |  Object | Rating 
1     |  101    | 1.5 
1     |  102    | 2 
1     |  103    | 1 
2     |  101    | -1  
2     |  102    | 2     
3     |  101    | 1.5  
3     |  103    | 2  
4     |  103    | 2 
4     |  104    | -2
```

For each entry in the dataframe, I want to multiply the rating by a pre-calculated weight, and put it in a new column. I already have a pre-defined dataframe of weights:

```
User  |  Weight 
1     |  0.5    
2     |  1     
3     |  0.75   
4     |  0.25
```

For example, for each entry in the dataframe under user 1, I will take the rating in that row and multiply it by 0.5. Resulting dataframe should look something like this:

```
User  |  Object | Rating | New Variable
1     |  101    | 1.5    | 0.75
1     |  102    | 2      | 1
1     |  103    | 1      | 0.5
2     |  101    | -1     | -1
2     |  102    | 2      | 2
3     |  101    | 1.5    | 1.125
3     |  103    | 2      | 1.5
4     |  103    | 2      | 0.5
4     |  104    | -2     | -0.5
```

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I can't figure it out. Would love some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "User") %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = Weight * Rating) %>% 
  select(-Weight)

#   User Object Rating new_variable
# 1    1    101    1.5        0.750
# 2    1    102    2.0        1.000
# 3    1    103    1.0        0.500
# 4    2    101   -1.0       -1.000
# 5    2    102    2.0        2.000
# 6    3    101    1.5        1.125
# 7    3    103    2.0        1.500
# 8    4    103    2.0        0.500
# 9    4    104   -2.0       -0.500
```

Data

```r
df1 <- read.csv(text = "User  |  Object | Rating 
1     |  101    | 1.5 
1     |  102    | 2 
1     |  103    | 1 
2     |  101    | -1  
2     |  102    | 2     
3     |  101    | 1.5  
3     |  103    | 2  
4     |  103    | 2 
4     |  104    | -2", sep = "|")

df2 <- read.csv(text = "User  |  Weight 
1     |  0.5    
2     |  1     
3     |  0.75   
4     |  0.25", sep = "|")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R:

```
df1$new_variable <- df1$Rating*df2$Weight[match(df1$User, df2$User)]
df1
  User Object Rating new_variable
1    1    101    1.5        0.750
2    1    102    2.0        1.000
3    1    103    1.0        0.500
4    2    101   -1.0       -1.000
5    2    102    2.0        2.000
6    3    101    1.5        1.125
7    3    103    2.0        1.500
8    4    103    2.0        0.500
9    4    104   -2.0       -0.500
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried the dplyr method suggested above. But since I have a large dataset, I was wondering if the base R method would be faster?

Comment: With high probability, it's fair to assume that dplyr would be faster than base R.